# How to hide field value only

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, field

Hi is there any way not to display only the value of the below field?

I want to use the value of the field. I just want not to display it only.

```
items.push('<tr><td style="border: 0px;"><input type="number" name="' + row.flatno + '" id="' + row.flatno + '" flat="' + row.flatdescription + '" building="' + row.buildingcode + '" class="field" value="' + row.previousmetric + '" valuep="' + row.previousmetric + '"/></td></tr>');
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  You want to USE the value but you don't want it displayed?

Comment: Do you want the textbox to be displayed as empty, but with an actual value in it that you can retrieve by calling `myInput.value`?

Comment: yes that is what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

By field I assume you mean input.

Make the input element hidden, that is `<input type="hidden" id="input">`. 
To use it give it an id then use the value by using the code in a javascript method : `$("#input").val()`

Comment: I want to display an empty textbox field but with an actual value in it

Comment: Um no idea, unless you can make the forecolor white? But if you highlight the text you see it. Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: You can have a look at this maybe: http://developerkarma.com/blog/andrew-m-riley/using-jquery-hide-value-text-fields-focus

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="hidden" id="hid1" value="100" />`

This won't be seen on the screen but you can access the values stored in it

Comment: I want to display an empty textbox field but with an actual value in it